# Why is the constructor invoked despite calling createStubInstance?

Tags: node.js, sinon

I want to prevent the constructor of a class being called during a test so I used `createStubInstance(MyClass)` as per the docs, but the constructor still gets invoked. Why?

> If you want to create a stub object of MyConstructor, but don’t want
>   the constructor to be invoked, use this utility function.
>
> var stub = sinon.createStubInstance(MyConstructor)

**Test**

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const Fizz = require('../Fizz')
const Buzz = require('../Buzz')


    describe('Fizz', () => {
      it('should mock the constructor', () => {
        sinon.createStubInstance(Fizz)
        const doStuffFakeFizz = sinon.stub(Fizz.prototype, 'doStuff').returns({ src: 'mock' })
        const buzz = new Buzz()
        buzz.doStuff()
        expect(doStuffFakeFizz.called).toBeTruthy()
      })
    })
```

**Buzz**

```
const Fizz = require('./Fizz')

    class Buzz {
      doStuff() {
        const fizz = new Fizz()
        return fizz.doStuff()
      }
    }
    module.exports = Buzz
```

**Fizz**

```
class Fizz {
  constructor() {
    console.log('CALLED')
    this.thing = { src: 'real' }
  }

  doStuff() {
    return this.thing
  }
}
module.exports = Fizz
```

Answer (score 2):

`sinon.createStubInstance` can't replace references like that. All it does is return a plain object with a stub in place for each property in the constructor's prototype. You'll usually make this object the return value of some stub, or provide it as an argument somewhere, in order to get it into place.

In order to actually stub the Fizz constructor, your code under test needs to invoke it by means of a reference that can be replaced. See my answer here:

[Can ES6 constructors be stubbed more easily with Sinon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142026/can-es6-constructors-be-stubbed-more-easily-with-sinon/49563139#49563139)