# Creating a Stub Instance Using createStubInstance: Constructor Not Skipped as Expected

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following problem:

I have a class, which is a State controller and I want to test it when its in the "start" state. In particular its update method, which switches to the next state when updated with particular events

```
export class StateController implements IOBserver{
    private logger: LoggerService;

    private stateConfiguration: StateConfiguration | undefined;

    private currStateNum: number;

    private maxStateNum: number;

    private controllerName: string;

    constructor(stateName: string) {
        this.controllerName = StateController.name;
        this.logger = ServiceLocator.Current.get<LoggerService>(LoggerService.name);
        this.stateConfiguration = new StateData().getSelectedStateConfiguration(stateName);
        this.currStateNum = 0;
        this.maxStateNum = 0;
    }

    public async startStateMachine() {
        // .. starting the state machine
    }

    public async update(event: EventType): Promise<void> {
        if (event === EventType.Finish) {
            await this.transitionToNextState();
        } else {
            if (event === EventType.UnknownError || event === EventType.UnresolvableError) {
                await new CleanUpState().onStart();
                process.exit(1);
            } else {
                await new RecoveryState(event).onStart();
            }
        }
    }

    private async goToNextState(): Promise<void> {
      // ...
    }
```

In the constructor you can see we have the stateConfiguration, which looks like that:

```
export class StateData {

    public getSelectedStateConfiguration(stateName: string): StateConfiguration | undefined {
        switch (stateName) {
            case 'start':
                return this.getStartConfiguration();
            // Other state cases
        }
    }

    private getStartConfiguration(): StateConfiguration {
        return {
            'stateMachineName' : 'start',
            'states' : [
                new InitState(),
                new StartState(),
                new NetworkPrepState(),
                new AccountCreationState(),
                new CleanUpState(),
                new AttachState()
                
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

I have written the following two tests, however the second one does not work, because it tries to go through the constructor of the CleanUpState, although I am creating a stubInstance and I would expect it to not go through the constructor of the CleanUpState

The test file:

```
// .. imports 

describe('StateController', () => {
  let stateController: StateController;
  let serviceLocatorStub: sinon.SinonStub;
  let cleanUpStateStub: sinon.SinonStubbedInstance<CleanUpState>;
  let cleanUpStateStub2 : sinon.SinonStubbedInstance<CleanUpState>;
  let getStartConfigurationStub: sinon.SinonStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Create a stub for the ServiceLocator
    const stubbedInitState = sinon.createStubInstance(InitState);
    const stubbedStartState = sinon.createStubInstance(StartState);
    const stubbedNetworkPrepState = sinon.createStubInstance(NetworkPrepState);
    const stubbedAccountCreationState = sinon.createStubInstance(AccountCreationState);
    cleanUpStateStub = sinon.createStubInstance(CleanUpState);
    cleanUpStateStub.onStart.resolves();
    const stubbedAttachState = sinon.createStubInstance(AttachState);
    const loggerServiceStub = sinon.createStubInstance(LoggerService);

    serviceLocatorStub = sinon.stub(ServiceLocator.Current, 'get').returns(loggerServiceStub);

    getStartConfigurationStub = sinon.stub(StateData.prototype, <any>"getStartConfiguration").returns({
        'stateMachineName' : 'start',
        'states' : [
          stubbedInitState,
          stubbedStartState,
          stubbedNetworkPrepState,
          stubbedAccountCreationState,
          cleanUpStateStub,
          stubbedAttachState
        ]
    });
    stateController = new StateController('start');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // Restore the original ServiceLocator after each test
    cleanUpStateStub.onStart.restore();
    serviceLocatorStub.restore();
    getStartConfigurationStub.restore();
  });

  it('should transition to next state on Finish event', async () => {
    // Starting the state machine
    await stateController.startStateMachine();

    // Sending two finish events
    await stateController.update(EventType.Finish);
    await stateController.update(EventType.Finish);

    expect(stateController['currStateNum']).to.equal(2);
  });


  it('should handle other events correctly', async () => {
    // Arrange
    // Stub process.exit
    const processExitStub = sinon.stub(process, 'exit');
    // Act
    // await stateController.update(EventType.UnknownError);
    await stateController.update(EventType.UnresolvableError);

    // Assert
    assert.isTrue(cleanUpStateStub2.onStart.calledOnce);
    assert.isTrue(processExitStub.calledWith(1));
  });
});
```

As you can see I use a stubInstance and stub the onStart but it is not working.

The way the CleanUpState is called in the *else* in the *update* method is similar to the way StateData is used in the constructor. I stubbed the getSelectedStateConfiguration and I tried the same way for the CleanUpState but its also not working

```
getStartConfigurationStub = sinon.stub(CleanUpState.prototype, <any>"onStart").resolved();
```

I have read this [Can ES6 constructors be stubbed more easily with Sinon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142026/can-es6-constructors-be-stubbed-more-easily-with-sinon/49563139#49563139) but I still do not quite get why this wont work, but it works for StateData